# Can I enumerate a variable group in VSTS?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

**TL;DR:** Search and replace placeholders in a text file with the decrypted values of secrets in a variable group.

I would like to use a PowerShell script to receive a variable group in a release pipeline and then iterate through the list, performing search-and-replace on a file being released.

The **variables in the variable list are secrets** so I want to overwrite the placeholders in the file with the decrypted value of the variables.

The values of the variables are environment specific, so I do not want to provide the values at build time and do not want to include the decrypted values in a stored artifact.

The file being search-replaced will be used in an execution at release time but will not be deployed to a host, so will be destroyed upon completion of the pipeline execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've found that, as long as I have a [Base64 token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) configured for Variable Groups (click 'Show all scopes' when creating a new PAT) then I can call `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1` to [get the variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) I need.

The above, however, will not return a value for secrets, although there is a [hack/workaround for this (involving multiple pipeline steps)](https://arapaima.uk/post/2017-10-23-vsts-secret-environment-variables/).

The advisable route is to create a [Key Vault in Azure and perform the processing either in Powershell or code.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/quick-create-powershell)

As I need the decrypted key values passed into my application via a repeated find-replace, I have implemented a Powershell script in one Release pipeline step and consume the output in the next step.

Answer (score 1):

The Tokenization task from the Visual Studio Marketplace does this job well.  You'll need to install it into your Azure DevOps organisation, it's available at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TotalALM.totalalm-tokenization

By default the Tokenization task uses double underscores to identify the placeholders.  It will replace any text that that matches the name of a variable in your release definition as long as it's surrounded by double underscores.

So if you want to write the value of a variable called MySecretVariable into your file you'll need to add a place holder like `__MySecretVariable__` into the file where ever you want that value to be written.

The Tokenization task will write any encrypted values into the file in plain text but in the release logs they will be obfuscated.

If you're storing your variables in a variable group just link that to the release definition and set the scope to the appropriate environment.